# How to extends/subcontents a dialog box using the GWT UiBinder?

Tags: gwt, uibinder

I want to build "from scratch" a DialogBox hierarchy. First of all, I've got

- a **BaseDialog.java** class : A simple dialog that extends DialogBox (gwt widget)

  ```
  public class BaseDialog extends DialogBox {

      protected static BaseDialog2UiBinder uiBinder = GWT
              .create(BaseDialog2UiBinder.class);

      interface BaseDialog2UiBinder extends UiBinder<Widget, BaseDialog2> {
      }

      @UiField
      protected FlowPanel contentPanel;

      public BaseDialog() {
          setWidget(uiBinder.createAndBindUi(this));
      }
  }
  ```
- a **BaseDialog.ui.xml**

  ```
  <!DOCTYPE ui:UiBinder SYSTEM "http://dl.google.com/gwt/DTD/xhtml.ent">
  <ui:UiBinder xmlns:ui="urn:ui:com.google.gwt.uibinder"
      xmlns:g="urn:import:com.google.gwt.user.client.ui">

      <g:VerticalPanel width="200px" height="200px">
          <g:Label>Label principal</g:Label>
          <g:FlowPanel ui:field="contentPanel" />
      </g:VerticalPanel>

  </ui:UiBinder>
  ```

As you can see, the BaseDialog contains a simple Label and a contentPanel (FlowPanel).

I would like to extends the BaseDialog (e.g. ConfirmationDialog). The ConfirmationDialog fills the content of the BaseDialog's contentPanel.

How can I do that ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, I have found the solution :

```
public class ConfirmationBox extends BaseDialog2 {
  protected static ConfirmationBoxUiBinder uiBinder = GWT.create(ConfirmationBoxUiBinder.class);

  interface ConfirmationBoxUiBinder extends UiBinder<Widget, ConfirmationBox> {
  }

  @UiField
  Label helloLabel;

  public ConfirmationBox() {
    contentPanel.add(uiBinder.createAndBindUi(this));
  }
}
```

And

```
<!DOCTYPE ui:UiBinder SYSTEM "http://dl.google.com/gwt/DTD/xhtml.ent">
<ui:UiBinder xmlns:ui="urn:ui:com.google.gwt.uibinder"
    xmlns:g="urn:import:com.google.gwt.user.client.ui" xmlns:my="urn:import:com.guardis.cortex.web.client.dialog">

    <g:FlowPanel>
        <my:BaseDialog2>
            <g:FlowPanel ui:field="contentPanel">
                <g:Label>test contentPanel from confirmationBox</g:Label>
            </g:FlowPanel>
        </my:BaseDialog2>
        <g:Label ui:field="helloLabel">Hello world from confirmation box (outside of BaseDialog)</g:Label>
    </g:FlowPanel>
</ui:UiBinder>
```

Comment: In your answer you extend from BaseDialog2, but in the question your class is BaseDialog.  I am guessing that they are the same?

Also, do you still do it this way, or have you found a better way?